# MediaRecorder start called in invalid state: 4 || E/AudioRecording: prepare() failed

Tags: java, android, androidx, android-mediarecorder, android-audiorecord

I'm with a big problem in my Record Audio App, and I read every post related to it in this site, and tryied every solution suggested, but didn't solved my problem. My app works fine in all Android versions from AndroidQ *10.0*(SDK29) and bellow, and this problems **only appears at version 10.0+**, specifically in **SDK30**. Does anyone knows how to solve it, or maybe, have any idea about what is causing this bug?

**Here is a print of the log:** [https://imgur.com/a/xSATHSp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaCd7.png)
**The Manifest:** [https://imgur.com/a/T6eEGmb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ab7zf.png)
**The Code(line76):** [https://imgur.com/a/lrmlB58](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trc5Z.png)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I also tryied other solutions from another foruns, like this one, in the section "**What could go wrong?**" *at subtopic* **"*java.lang.IllegalStateException*":** https://www.grokkingandroid.com/recording-audio-using-androids-mediarecorder-framework/
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
**My log exception:**

```
E/AudioRecording: prepare() failed
E/MediaRecorder: start called in an invalid state: 4
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myfetus, PID: 17985
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
        at com.example.myfetus.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:81)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

**My ActivityMain code:**

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private ImageButton recordbtn, stopbtn, playbtn, stopplay, pausebtn;
    private MediaRecorder mRecorder;
    private MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "AudioRecording";
    private static String mFileName = null;
    public static final int REQUEST_AUDIO_PERMISSION_CODE = 1;
    private int buttonState = 0;
    private EditText editsenha1;
    private TextView test1;
    private ImageView editImagem;
    private int i=0;
    Date createdTime = new Date();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recordbtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.record);
        stopbtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.stopRecord);
        playbtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.play);
        stopplay = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.stopplay);
        pausebtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.pause);
        stopbtn.setEnabled(false);
        playbtn.setEnabled(false);
        stopplay.setEnabled(false);

        mFileName = (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "MyFetus" +createdTime + "Audio.m4a").replaceAll(" ", "_").replaceAll(":", "-");
        test1 = findViewById(R.id.texto2);
         editImagem = findViewById(R.id.imageView4);

        recordbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (CheckPermissions()) {
                        stopbtn.setEnabled(true);
                        recordbtn.setEnabled(false);
                        playbtn.setEnabled(false);
                        stopplay.setEnabled(false);
                        pausebtn.setEnabled(false);
                        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
                        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
                        mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(128000);
                        mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
                        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
                        try {
                            mRecorder.prepare();

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
                        }
                        mRecorder.start();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        test1.setText("Gravando...");
                        test1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0af263"));
                    } else {
                        RequestPermissions();
                    }
                    recordbtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    stopbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }


        });
        stopbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopbtn.setEnabled(false);
                recordbtn.setEnabled(true);
                playbtn.setEnabled(true);
                stopplay.setEnabled(true);
                pausebtn.setEnabled(true);
                mRecorder.stop();
                mRecorder.release();
                mRecorder = null;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                test1.setText("Aperte para gravar");
                test1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FADCEE"));
                stopbtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                recordbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        playbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopbtn.setEnabled(false);
                recordbtn.setEnabled(true);
                playbtn.setEnabled(false);
                stopplay.setEnabled(true);
                pausebtn.setEnabled(true);
                mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                try {
                    mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);
                    mPlayer.prepare();
                    mPlayer.start();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording Started Playing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
                }
            }
        });
        pausebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mPlayer!=null){
                mPlayer.pause();
                stopbtn.setEnabled(true);
                recordbtn.setEnabled(true);
                playbtn.setEnabled(true);
                stopplay.setEnabled(true);
                pausebtn.setEnabled(false);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Audio Paused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
            }
        });
        stopplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mPlayer.release();
                mPlayer = null;
                stopbtn.setEnabled(false);
                recordbtn.setEnabled(true);
                playbtn.setEnabled(true);
                stopplay.setEnabled(false);
                pausebtn.setEnabled(true);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Audio Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_AUDIO_PERMISSION_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length> 0) {
                    boolean permissionToRecord = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean permissionToStore = grantResults[1] ==  PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    if (permissionToRecord && permissionToStore) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Permission Denied",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    public boolean CheckPermissions() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), RECORD_AUDIO);
        return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }
    private void RequestPermissions() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{RECORD_AUDIO, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_AUDIO_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide links to the questions you read, and the solutions you tried.

Comment: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640734/mediarecorder-ioexception-prepare-failed)

[link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37290752/java-lang-runtimeexception-setaudiosource-failed/39920574)

[link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19558812/android-mediarecorder-start-failed-in-invalid-state-4/57230642)

[link] (https://www.manongdao.com/q-1003432.html)

[link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236620/mediarecorder-start-called-in-invalid-state-4)
[link](https://www.programmersought.com/article/13341635804/)
@HappyFace

Comment: The stacktrace in the question is irrelevant. That's simply because you ignore the failure of `prepare()` and call `start()` anyway.  Please add the error to the log statement within the catch block. That exception contains the interesting information missing in your question.
And do *not* continue if `prepare()` failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing with Android 10 upwards is, that you [cannot access files on the external SD card anymore](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#scoped-storage). You have to use either the Storage Access Framework to create a file first and then use it as a base for storing, or you only use app private storage.

Or - IMHO better in this case - you use the [`MediaStore` content provider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore). See the official docs for more details about [how to add files to MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#add-item).

If you use `MediaStore` you canot use `setOutputfile()` anymore. Use `setOutputFileDescriptor()`instead with the `FileDescriptor` you can get from the `MediaStore` content provider.